# What data structure is best for this task?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Advise how best to organize this code. The task is essentially simple:
Given A, B, C are numerical variables. Between them can be the following relationships:

A > B > C

A < B < C

Also numerical variable X given. This variable can be equal to A, B, C (3 options), can be in the intervals between them (2 options), and go beyond (be less than A, or more than C (2 options)). 7 options total. Given that there can be both A > B > C and A < B < C, we multiply the number of options by 2, totaling 14 possible options for X.

I solved this problem this way:

```
  if (X < A) { 
    // do something
  }
  if (X == A) {
    // do something else
  }
  if (X > A && X < B) {
    // another thing
  }
  // and so on..
}
```

This code works, but it is cumbersome (a bunch of if's) and not very readable (in reality, the names of the variables are different and there is more code). How can I organize this code in a different way? Is it possible to choose a data structure that will make the code more concise and simple? Or describe conditional checks differently?

Comment: do you have some examples? with values?

Comment: @NinaScholz for example: A=1, B=5, C=7, and X= 4. Or A=7, B=5, C=1 and X=6

Comment: I don't think you need a datastructure for this. Also, making the code concise will depend on whether the bodies of your if-statements are similar in a certain way (which I believe is your case). So I think showing the instructions inside `ifs` will help.

Comment: @Sarmon thanks for the answer. But what do you mean by showing instructions?

Comment: I meant perhaps you can show us what the code looks like inside your if-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rules engines concept.

- Define your rules (assuming A, B, C are some constants)

  ```
  rules = [
          {
            "rule" : (X) => X > A,
            "action": (X) => { console.log("first rule passed")}
          },
          {
            "rule" : (X) => X == A,
            "action": (X) => { console.log("second rule passed")}
          },
          {
            "rule" : (X) => X > A && X < B,
            "action": (X) => { console.log("third rule passed")}
          }
          ..

     ];
  ```
- Execute your rules as shown here.

`rules.filter(r => r.rule(x)).forEach(r => r.action());`

Comment: thx, that is good solution. I tried to google "rule engines" but got some irrelevant results. How to read more about this technique? Does it have name? Or it is just "rule engines concept"?

Comment: There are many libraries for rules engine in java. I am not familiar with javascript. Check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rules-engine

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to get rid of the 14 if statements, but one solution to make it *possibly* more readable at the price of complexity, is to have a function that takes arguments X, A, B and C and returns an enum with one of 14 items. You then have a switch statement for the various 14 tasks.

It *might* show a clearer intention with one part going "here are 4 arguments, make a domain value out of it" and one part going "here is a domain value, make some stuff with it".

A bit like:

```
function react(driver, car, road, traffic){
  if( driver < car ) return action.increasevolume;
  if( car === traffic ) return action.speedup;
  if( ...
}

switch( react( driver, car, road, traffic  )) {
  case action.increasevolume:
    ...
  break;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can reduce the number of tests you have to code for, but you can improve the running time by implementing a simple binary search, which reduces the number of cases you actually test.

If it's always the case that one of `A < B < C` or `A > B > C` is true, then you halve the number of tests with a simple check to see if `A < B`. You can then refine it further:

```
if (A < B)
{
    if (X < B)
    {
        if (X < A)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else if (X == A)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else // A < X < B
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
    else if (X < C)
    {
        if (X == B)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else // B > X < C
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
    else if (X == C)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else // X > C
    {
        // do something
    }
}
else  // A > B > C
{
    // similar logic as above
}
```

A little messy, but fewer comparisons and likely a little faster, although it's unlikely to make much practical difference.

You could eliminate the duplicated logic for the `A > B > C` case by writing a function `f(x, a, b, c)`, and for the `A > B > C` case, call it with the `A`, `B`, and `C` parameters reversed. You'll have to modify the returned result afterward, but that's a simple enough mapping.